# minDate or maxDate not working in AlloyUI 1.5 DatePickerSelect

Tags: javascript, liferay, yui, alloy-ui

Trying to set limit on date selection range for user.

I have tried all option "minDate/maxDate/minimumDate/MaximumDate". None is working.

it should work as mentioned on below comment from debug js:

```
<div >
    <div class="aui-datepicker aui-datepicker-display aui-helper-clearfix" id="datePickerBB">
    <div class="aui-datepicker-content" id="srcNode">
        <div class="aui-datepicker-select-wrapper">
            <select id="yearNode" class="custom-field aui-datepicker-year">
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
            </select>
            <select id="monthNode" class="custom-field aui-datepicker-month">
                <option value="0">January</option>
                <option value="1">February</option>
                <option value="2">March</option>
                <option value="3">April</option>
                <option value="4">May</option>
                <option value="5" selected>June</option>
                <option value="6">July</option>
                <option value="7">August</option>
                <option value="8">September</option>
                <option value="9">October</option>
                <option value="10">November</option>
                <option value="11">December</option>
            </select>
            <select id="dayNode" class="custom-field aui-datepicker-day">
                <option value="9">9</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="aui-datepicker-button-wrapper">
            <button type="button" id="buttonTest" class="aui-buttonitem-content aui-widget aui-component aui-buttonitem aui-state-default aui-buttonitem-icon-only">
                <span class="aui-buttonitem-icon aui-icon aui-icon-calendar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
* The minimum date that can be displayed by the calendar. The calendar will not
 * allow dates earlier than this one to be set, and will reset any earlier date to
 * this date. Should be `null` if no minimum date is needed.

AUI().use('aui-datepicker', function(A) {
/*
    Simple Datepicker
*/

    var datepicker2 = new A.DatePickerSelect({
    srcNode: '#srcNode',
    contentBox: '#srcNode',
    boundingBox: '#datePickerBB',
    minDate: new Date(2016,00,1),
    appendOrder: [ 'y', 'm', 'd' ],
    calendar: {
         date: new Date(2016,02,20),
         dateFormat: '%d/%m/%y',
         minDate: new Date(2015,10,10),
         maxDate: new Date(),
         minimumDate: new Date(2015,10,10),
         maximumDate: new Date(),   
    },
})
.render();
});
```

It is not throwing any error in console. I can use only AlloyUI 1.5.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think that when you are setting the `date` attribute on the calendar, that is also being ignored. I found that if you want a default date for a `DatePickerSelect`, you can use [the `Calendar`'s `dates` attribute](http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/api/classes/Calendar.html#attr_dates) instead: `dates:  [ new Date(2016,02,20) ],`.

Comment: Just so you know, your question code has a few issues: 1. It is not an mcve. 2. The initial date which you are setting by the `date` attribute is greater than the `maxDate`. 3. I don't  think `srcNode` and `contentBox` should point to the same element. I've made an edit to your question to fix these issues (actually, I tried to make it into an mcve and all the other problems could be deleted since they were unrelated to your actual problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, initializing the calendar with the [`minDate`](http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/api/classes/Calendar.html#attr_minDate) and [`maxDate`](http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/api/classes/Calendar.html#attr_maxDate) attributes does not work with [`DatePickerSelect`](http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/examples/datepicker/) in AlloyUI 1.5. It's probably a bug, but AlloyUI 1.5 is so old that I doubt that it would get fixed. To workaround this, you can set the `DatePickerSelect` calendar's `minDate` and `maxDate` after initialization:

```
datePickerSelect.calendar.set('minDate', new Date(2015,10,10));
datePickerSelect.calendar.set('maxDate', new Date());
```

It won't have any effect on the values of the `<select>`s unfortunately, so the user will still be able to pick bad values from them. You can mitigate some of this problem by setting [the `DatePickerSelect` `yearRange` attribute](http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/api/classes/DatePickerSelect.html#attr_yearRange).

Runnable example:

```js
AUI().use('aui-datepicker', function(A) {

  var datePickerSelect = new A.DatePickerSelect({
    yearRange: [2015, 2016],
  }).render();

  datePickerSelect.calendar.set('minDate', new Date(2015, 10, 10));
  datePickerSelect.calendar.set('maxDate', new Date());
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/1.5.1/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/1.5.1/aui-skin-classic/css/aui-skin-classic-all-min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```